# Creating a good login logic

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, authentication, local-storage

If we use SESSION, it will be only one session. I want user will be able to login in 2 days, or specific, so i dont use SESSION

So, im trying cookies/localStorage. But, we can inject/ create new cookie manually via browser developer tool.
when we set cookie in php

```
setcookie('isLoggedin', 'yes', time()+3600);
```

Then via developer tools, we can just manually create cookie with name `isLoggedin` with value `yes`

So, how to do good login logic?
I think everything will be the same even on html5 localStorage if i don't know the logic. Currently, my way is by storing encrypted password on cookie/localStorage, then verify it to server for every page reload, but im sure, this is also bad practice.

Comment: @CORRUPT : i've go to your link and referrenced links inside.. but i didn't found it answers my question about good login logic

Comment: Good logic is .. hard to define. One possible way is to set isLoggedin to a secreit token that you save a copy on your server. So when checking for the identify of the person, the token as to match. Make the token into a long random string so that even if people try to fake a cookie entry, they can't generate the correct token.

Comment: Btw, most systems allows you to tweak how long a session lives. And most systems use cookies to acheive sessions. That's why if security is a big issue, like banking sites, they don't implement prolonged sessions or an auto sign in feature.

Comment: @user1600124 : Thank you very much for your good explanation.. yes.. i will consider session again.. yes, maybe a long token then verify to server would help